# How to generate a datagrid like control in WPF with a specific size like 10X10?

Tags: wpf

I am very new to WPF and need to design a datagrid like structure that have a predefined size (for e.g., 10 X 10, 6x7 and so on). The first column in this should work as a row header and first row should work like column header and the rest of the cell should be populated dynamically based on some list or any other datasource.

The sample shows the structure that I want to generate dynamically, the size of the matrix may vary all the time:

[image]

Comment: If you use a DataGrid, the columns and rows have their own headers like in Excel. Is this what you want to achieve? If so, I can provide you with some code to achieve that.

Comment: Yes, I want it like that but the values in the column and row's headers also coming dynamically, its not fixed all the time

Comment: Can you explain where this dynamic data is coming from? like which DataType it is, etc.? You should look into wpf Binding()!

Comment: The answer i provided is for a static approach, but if you answer my previous question i can help you with a different approach!

Comment: This dynamic data is coming from a list<object> (strictly typed), where the list is bind with the data coming from a database.

Comment: @NickGames, Yes this approach works good for static data only, but as I mentioned I have dynamic data in a list in which each item contains the cell position as well as data. Like, for column 0, row 1 the data should be 1, for column 1 row 3, there should be value 5. All these data coming from a dynamic list that is coming from the database.

Answer (score -1):

Assuming your DataGrid is named "MyDataGrid";

Warning: Headers cannot contain spaces!

To add new columns with headers:

```
MyDataGrid.Columns.Add(
new DataGridTextColumn()
{
Header = "MyHeader1",
Binding = new Binding() { Path = new PropertyPath("MyHeader1")
}
});
MyDataGrid.Columns.Add(
new DataGridTextColumn()
{
Header = "MyHeader2",
Binding = new Binding() { Path = new PropertyPath("MyHeader2")
}
});
```

To add new Rows:

```
MyDataGrid.Items.Add(new { MyHeader1 = "Text in cell 1", MyHeader2 = "Text in cell 2"});
```